# Comparing Mann-Whitney U Statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

as the title states, I am wondering whether there are common ways to compare Mann-Whitney U Statistics. I have a unique dataset in which each sample has been acquired via two different methods. I have $H_{0} : X_{1,i} = X_{2,i}$, $H_a : X_{1,i} < X_{2,i}$ as in the natural Mann-Whitney U Test, $i \in \{1, 2\}$, and will be quantified with the Mann-Whitney U Statistic. What I am then interested is whether this effect is more, or less, substantial in $i=1$ vs $i=2$. Any ideas how to test whether one mann-whitney statistic exceeds another?

Comment: You say "*whether this effect is more, or less, substantial*"; that's a desire to compare some sort of effect, rather than test statistics (also keep in mind that hypotheses are about populations, not samples). Further note that if your data are two different methods on the same subjects, you have pairing on subject. You would need to identify what quantity represents the effect of interest here.

Comment: e.g. If you want to think of a Mann-Whitney as a hypothesis about a population proportion (which it is, in its most general form), I think it's possible to get somewhere with that. Or if you want to look at it as a test of location shift (which you can get to by adding assumptions) you could have a hypothesis about differences there.

Comment: In R, you can get a nonparametric CI along with test results. Look at widths of the two CIs. If you have paired data as ~Glen_b suggests, then you can get a CI for the difference.

Comment: Hey guys; really appreciate the feedback; looking at the nonparametric CIs is a great idea. Do you have any links I can check into? Also @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica to be more specific I suppose, I'm interested in non-parametrically testing whether the difference of a difference of means is positive, where there is pairing of the "outer" difference (ie, the between-sample difference), but the "inner" difference is unpaired (ie, the within-sample difference); so apologies for the confusion.

Comment: and when I say "sample" here, my population of interested for the inner test is all a selection of features collected from a single sample (the "inner difference"). Basically, some property of these features has an effect which we quantify with Mann U, and that effect is stronger when data prepared one way vs the other (which I also want to quantify in a non-parametric fashion). maybe that makes more sense?